# Does it make sense to decouple application layers and have different pom files for them?

Tags: java, maven, architecture

I recently ran into a project that was decoupled into 4 layers:
Service
Controller
DB
Model
and there was a pom.xml for each of these layers. Of course, one of them was the parent and the others were child(s).
It looked to me like it was a bit of overkill, but again any layer could be swapped out super easily. 
What do you guys think? any useful use cases? or do you think it would be a bit too much? Thanks.

Comment: Almost any non-trivial decoupling is a good idea in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pros and cons of this approach. 
Pros.
If in future you have to develop some module that depends on only model or service then you dont need to refactor your code.you can just put dependencies and work will be done.In my last project we have to develop one component for offline processing and that component was deployed in seperate server.

Cons. You will have to deal with multiple jars and if you are not packaging your application in one bundle then its management can be messy.

I believe its worth taking pain and creating separate modules even if it is over kill .it can really help in tdd environments